"When Do Cevians and Circumcircle Intersections Align? A Concurrency Proof Challenge"

Problem
Let $\triangle ABC$ be a given triangle with an interior point $P$, and let $X_1$, $Y_1$, and $Z_1$ be the points where lines $AP$, $BP$, and $CP$ intersect sides $BC$, $CA$, and $AB$, respectively. I need to prove that the lines $AX_3$, $BY_3$, and $CZ_3$ are concurrent, where $X_3$, $Y_3$, and $Z_3$ are the second intersections of the circumcircle of $\triangle X_1 Y_1 Z_1$ with sides $BC$, $CA$, and $AB$, respectively.

Observations and Attempts
Nine-Point Circle Analogy I noticed that if $P$ were the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$, then $X_1$, $Y_1$, and $Z_1$ would be the feet of the altitudes, and the circumcircle of $\triangle X_1 Y_1 Z_1$ would correspond to the nine-point circle of $\triangle ABC$. This circle would then intersect the sides $BC$, $CA$, and $AB$ again at the midpoints of these sides, which are exactly $X_3$, $Y_3$, and $Z_3$.
Concurrency via the Nine-Point Circle For the case where $P$ is the orthocenter, it’s known that the lines $AX_3$, $BY_3$, and $CZ_3$ are concurrent at the centroid of $\triangle ABC$. This result relies on the properties of the nine-point circle and symmetry in $\triangle ABC$.
General Case for an Interior Point $P$ In the general case where $P$ is any interior point, I suspect that a similar cyclic configuration might yield concurrency. Since $X_3$, $Y_3$, and $Z_3$ lie on the circumcircle of $\triangle X_1 Y_1 Z_1$, perhaps using a radical axis argument could help show the concurrency. However, without the orthocenter assumption, I’m not sure if the centroid remains the concurrency point or if it shifts based on $P$'s location.
Does anyone have insights on whether this line of reasoning could work for an arbitrary point $P$, or if there’s a different approach that might be more effective? Can anyone help me to complete the proof.


Have you tried using Ceva's theorem in combination with the intersecting chords/secants theorem?

(Echoing Duong) It's just Ceva's theorem with powers of a point. Write out what it means for $P$ to be concurrent, and for "$Q$" to be concurrent by Ceva's. How does power of a point $BZ_1 BZ_3 = BX_1 BX_3$ relate to those terms?

Following from Duong Ngo's hint:
By power of point, we have
$$AZ_3\cdot AZ_1 = AY_3 \cdot AY_1 \iff \frac{AZ_1}{AY_1} = \frac{AY_3}{AZ_3}$$
Similarly, we have
$$\frac{BX_1}{BZ_1} = \frac{BZ_3}{BX_3} \text{ and } \frac{CY_1}{CX_1} = \frac{CX_3}{CY_3}$$
Multiplying
$$\frac{AZ_3}{BZ_3}\cdot\frac{BX_3}{CX_3}\cdot\frac{CY_3}{AY_3} = \frac{AY_1}{CY_1}\cdot\frac{CX_1}{BX_1}\cdot\frac{BZ_1}{AZ_1} = 1 \tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$
